# Every time new Connection is returned from Ldap connection pool

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, connection-pooling

I have implemented LDAP connection pooling in my project and noticed a strange behavior that every time new connection request comes, LDAP connection pool I configured is returning new connection instead of re-using existing connection returned to pool.

**LDAP JNDI logs**:

```
00:07:10,824 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@46728c0f[eun2p3-be.stp-qa.st.com:636]
00:07:12,222 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@46728c0f
00:07:46,704 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@674b68bd expired
00:08:46,707 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@46728c0f expired
00:22:26,329 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@386bfda[eun2p3-be.stp-qa.st.com:636]
00:22:26,333 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@6d9f3716[eun2p3-be.stp-qa.st.com:636]
00:22:27,748 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@6d9f3716
00:22:46,730 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@386bfda expired
00:23:46,734 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@6d9f3716 expired
00:37:45,242 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4a21c217[eun2p3-be.stp-qa.st.com:636]
00:37:45,244 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@1b79ab6f[eun2p3-be.stp-qa.st.com:636]
00:37:46,759 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4a21c217 expired
00:37:46,823 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@1b79ab6f
00:39:46,764 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@1b79ab6f expired
00:53:00,864 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Create com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@668fc34[eun2p3-be.stp-qa.st.com:636]
00:53:00,865 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4674a7fb[eun2p3-be.stp-qa.st.com:636]
00:53:02,392 ERROR [stderr] (IPAdminGlobalDataReloader) Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4674a7fb
00:53:46,787 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@668fc34 expired
00:54:46,791 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-65) Expired com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4674a7fb expired
```

**My connection settings:**

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://" + server + ":" + serverPort);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, pUserName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pPassword);
    env.put(LdapContext.CONTROL_FACTORIES, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.ControlFactory");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "300000");

    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

    // load the location of keystore that holds trusted root certificates from web.xml
    ServletContext context = ApplicationServlet.getApplication().getServlet().getServletContext();
    String certificatePath = context.getInitParameter("AD_CERTIFICATE_PATH");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",  certificatePath);
    //          System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

    // For connection pooling
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol", "plain ssl");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize", poolMaxSize);
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize", poolPrefSize);
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout", poolTimeOut);
    System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug", "fine");

    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    return (DirContext) ctx;
```

Thanks in identifying where is the root cause, why every time new connection is created instead of reused.

Comment: Clearly your pool timeout is expiring. NB You haven't needed to add the SSL provider for ten years.

Comment: Connection Timeout is set for 5 minutes and as per logs connection is getting expired immediately.

Comment: ideally idle connection should wait for 5 minutes before expiry as timeout property is set for 5 minutes.

Comment: I discovered years ago by reading the source code of the JNDI LDAP provider that enabling connection pool logging disables the pool. So don't enable it.

Answer (score -2):

You have not implemented any connection pooling, you are using the broken `DirContext` connection pool from Sun. This is discouraged. Take a look at Spring LDAP's `ContextSource` pool. It works very well.

Comment: Make up your mind. Either he is using the SuN connection pooling or he isn't using any. The Sun JNDI connection pooling works for me,

Comment: And 'this is discouraged' by whom?