# Is context need to be closed explicity in LDAP connection pooling

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi

We are using below settings for LDAP JNDI connection pooling:

```
    DirContext ctx = null;
    try 
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://" + server + ":" + serverPort);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, pUserName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pPassword);
        env.put(LdapContext.CONTROL_FACTORIES, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.ControlFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "300000");

        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

        // load the location of keystore that holds trusted root certificates from web.xml
        ServletContext context = ApplicationServlet.getApplication().getServlet().getServletContext();
        String certificatePath = context.getInitParameter("AD_CERTIFICATE_PATH");

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",  certificatePath);
        //          System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

        // For connection pooling
        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol", "plain ssl");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize", poolMaxSize);
        System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize", poolPrefSize);
        System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout", poolTimeOut);
        System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug", "fine");

        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        return (DirContext) ctx;
```

---

After performing Search in Active Directory we are closing context explicitly using `ctx.close()` to release connection back to pool.

With above implementation we are facing issue that connection is closed immediately after getting connection:

> ```
> 12:06:14,837 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-22) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@26a2a0eb[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:16,855 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-22) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@26a2a0eb
> 12:06:18,301 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-23) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@76e26d4a[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:20,353 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-23) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@76e26d4a
> 12:06:21,713 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-19) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4bb50913[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:23,746 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-19) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@4bb50913
> 12:06:25,366 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-6) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@2a2eecb7[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:27,473 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-6) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@2a2eecb7
> 12:06:28,757 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-25) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3c34b0d[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:30,855 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-25) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@3c34b0d
> 12:06:32,214 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-22) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@6d9ca028[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:34,294 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-22) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@6d9ca028
> 12:06:35,730 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-23) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@72ed6bb2[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:37,753 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-23) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@72ed6bb2
> 12:06:39,184 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-19) Create and use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@e87ce30[eun1p3-be.stp-prod.st.com:636]
> 12:06:41,266 ERROR [stderr] (http-eul151.sgp.st.com-10.75.32.13-10080-19) Close com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@e87ce30
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Every time new Connection is returned from Ldap connection pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057672/every-time-new-connection-is-returned-from-ldap-connection-pool)

Comment: Yes actually, there I have asked different question on same code. Here I am facing issue connection is closed immediately.

Comment: Hi All, I have checked and did not get much on internet. As per oracle documentation it is mentioned that context need to closed in order to return it to pool.

Comment: BUt in our case after closing connections we are seeing when no of connection reaches maximum limit "20" in our case..connection is closed immediately after create and use..within 1 sec... I have shared logs above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to close not only all `Contexts` but also all `NamingEnumerations`. That's how connections get returned to the pool.

There is no evidence in your log that *connections* are being closed. What's being closed is `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClients.`

Comment: Thanks EJP, I got your point. I will close all NamingEnumerations.

Comment: One more point to clarify, we are calling HasMoreElements() on NamingEnumerations and correct me if I am wrong that if there is no more elements to be returned from NamingEnumeration then HasMoreElements() method take care of closing NamingEnumeration implicitly.

Comment: Supporting reference:  http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5084229

Comment: @RavinderKadian That's correct. ["If an enumeration proceeds to the end--that is, until hasMoreElements() or hasMore() returns false-- resources will be freed up automatically and there is no need to explicitly call close()."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingEnumeration.html#close()).

Comment: Thanks. I am able to resolve issue by explicitly closing all NamingEnumerations